# Rails aasm gem: "NoMethodError: undefined method" for event method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

Inside my Customer model I setup AASM on customer_status column, setting up an `activate` event too.

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  include AASM

  aasm column: :customer_status, whiny_transitions: true do
    state :active
    state :pending
    state :inactive
    state :cancelled

    event :activate do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :active
```

However, sporadically then the `activate` aasm call, i.e `customer.activate(args_here)`, may fail with:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'activate' for #<Customer id: .........>`

In case it matters, I have got same kind of error, again, sporadically and rarely, for status-related aasm methods. Eg. `customer.cancelled?` have failed with same error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cancelled?' for #<Customer id:
```

Does anyone have any idea what this is about? [Could not find a related issue on aasm gem](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/issues).

I would expect these aasm state-related and event-related methods to be available on the Customer object or at least be consistent. Why in the huge majority of cases no error is raised and in a tiny minority the error is raised, does not make sense to me.

**EDIT:**
Answering to the 1st question: No STI is used, and
`customer_status` field is 'character varying' in db (postgresql) and is defined as enum in Customer model, as such:

```
enum customer_status: {:active=>"active", :pending=>"pending", :inactive=>"inactive", :cancelled=>"cancelled"}
```

Also, keep in mind that this fails, but rarely, not all times, i.e works most of the time.

Comment: can you show more of your Customer class. are you using STI, and are you using enum columns?

Comment: @MarianTheisen appreciate your checking. I answered as an edit above.

Comment: i dont know if this is related, but you should set enum: true on the aasm declaration https://github.com/aasm/aasm#activerecord-enums

Comment: You are right @MarianTheisen thank you. I do not see how that can make it working in 99.99% and not in 0.01% of the cases, but it is a good catch for sure. Implemented it! I prefer to still keep this SO question open for a little bit more though.